# Issue using numpy.where to find zeroes in a large array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use np.where to exclude empty entries in a large array (loaded in using np.loadtxt), which python apparently takes as being equal to zero, I tried simply using `np.where(p>0)` before trying an same sized array of zeroes but got a similar error message where it wasn't supported between instances of arrays and floats/integers. X is the csv file

````
<ipython-input-10-033c18a45313> in <module>()
      3 p =x[1:, 4]
      4 zero = np.zeros((3161,), dtype=float)
----> 5 wer =np.where(p>zero)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray' ```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You/we need a clearer idea of what `x` is.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the `zero` array when doing this test.  `p>0` should be enough.  But `x/p` still needs to a numeric dtype array.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. Have you tried checking if:

```
print(p.dtype, zero.dtype)
```

give you either float64 or int64. Theoretically if they are both of the same type, they are comparable.

Comment: Uhm, it seems the p array's data type is called U29. I tried putting .astype(float) and (int) at the end of the definition for p, but it said it "could not convert string to float"